# Teechart VCl/Delphi : Use a second axis

Tags: delphi, vcl, teechart

I tried to use a teechart with a second axis but all the examples I found are not in Delphi.

I even tried ChatGPT but the code is wrong. It suggests Chart1.VerticalAxis := aRightAxis; but Chart1 has no .VerticalAxis.

Do you have an example of code in Delphi to make a series distributed in this second axis.

Thanks for your help and sorry for my poor English, next time I'll use ChatGPT

Comment: Don't use ChatGPT. If you care about quality or accuracy, you don't use ChatGTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not quite clear what you want to do, but perhaps the next:

Make two series in the chart

For the second one - assign Right Axis
(in visual editor of the chart: `Series-Series2-General tab - VerticalAxis combobox - Right`)

Also you can assign right axis to the only series if you want.

Also you can create new axes using - `Chart-Axis-Axes  +`   (not sure this option does exist in TChart Std)

Comment: **@MBo** : Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.